# windows asynchronous request limit

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, networking, asynchronous

I am building a c# application that resolves lots of domains into ip addresses asynchronously, using many DNS servers.

i am currently running 1000 requests per second on one windows 7 PC, when i try to run 2000 requests, it takes 2 seconds.

but when i try to run this extra 1000 requests on another windows 7 PC on the same LAN, simultaneously with the other PC, they both take 1 second to finish!

what make me think there is some sort of limitation on the amount of simultaneous asynchronous  requests that can be made on a single windows PC.

any one has any input on that matter? thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct.  The OS, and often even your network router, will have limits on the number of concurrent network requests.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960056/trying-to-run-multiple-http-requests-in-parallel-but-being-limited-by-windows

Comment: I have no idea what limit you might be exceeding because there is not enough information in the question about what you're doing.

Comment: Yuval Itzchakov, This refers to HTTP requests, i am doing DNS requests, it will not help.

Comment: Servy - It is not the router because i did the 2 PCs check on the same LAN

Comment: usr - What more information can i supply you?

Comment: Show your source code and provide your DNS settings.

Comment: EricLaw - My source code is too large to paste here, but i said what is relevant to the situation, and as for the DNS settings, as i said it runs on many DNS servers, non of which is relevant to the issue.